# How do I print out a timetable avoiding duplicates days?

Tags: php, html, mysql, string, datetime

I'm working on a website for a cinema and I have to print out the screenings schedule from a database.
The database has a `screenings` table with a `screening_start` datetime column. Every screening is saved by itself and has a unique id.

This is what the table looks like now:

```
id| movie_id| room_id|     screening_start    | reservations
  |         |        |                        |
2 |   10    |    1   |   2019-08-21 13:30:00  |  0
4 |   10    |    1   |   2019-08-20 16:30:00  |  0
5 |   10    |    1   |   2019-08-29 13:30:00  |  0
10|   10    |    1   |   2019-08-28 13:30:00  |  0
14|   10    |    1   |   2019-08-22 13:30:00  |  0
16|   10    |    1   |   2019-08-30 13:30:00  |  0
23|   10    |    1   |   2019-08-28 15:00:00  |  0
24|   10    |    1   |   2019-08-28 11:33:00  |  0
25|   10    |    1   |   2019-08-21 12:22:00  |  0
26|   10    |    1   |   2019-08-23 12:22:00  |  0
27|   10    |    1   |   2019-08-29 16:00:00  |  0
28|   21    |    2   |   2019-08-25 15:00:00  |  0
29|   10    |    1   |   2019-08-30 16:00:00  |  0
```

I'd like to print this out in a nice way.

So far I've only been able to print out the whole thing (by movie_id), but this way repeats the day of the week for each row.

```
<table>
    <?php 
         while ($row = $screenings->fetch_assoc()) {
            $date = date('l,j', strtotime($row['screening_start']));
            $time = date('H:i', strtotime($row['screening_start']));
    ?>
            <tr>
               <td><?php echo $date ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $time ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
         } 
    ?>
</table>
```

The result with this is:

```
Thursday, 22    13:30
Friday, 23      12:22
Wednesday, 28   11:33
Wednesday, 28   13:30
Wednesday, 28   15:00
Thursday, 29    13:30
Thursday, 29    16:00
Friday, 30      13:30
Friday, 30      16:00
```

and what I'm looking for would be something more like this:

```
Thursday, 22    13:30
Friday, 23      12:22
Wednesday, 28   11:33   13:30   15:00
Thursday, 29    13:30   16:00   
Friday, 30      13:30   16:00
```

Is it possible? Somehow I feel like the problem is within how I designed the MySQL table, do you agree with me?

Comment: No, I don't agree. The MySQL table's just fine. You just need to parse the result.

Comment: What you want is a basic one-level [control break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break) …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL table design looks good. You can do that in PHP.

First you group the results by day:

```
$data = [];

while ($row = $screenings->fetch_assoc()) {
    $day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['screening_start']));
    $data[$day][] = date('H:i', strtotime($row['screening_start']);
}
```

Then when outputting:

```
<?php 
 foreach ($data as $day => $times) {
    $date = date('l,j', strtotime($day));
?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $date ?></td>
       <td><?php echo implode(' ', $times) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What query you are using?
You can debug that using "[mysqli_fetch_all](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp)" function, if all repeated rows shows up then you have to change the your query first using distinct by date (not by time).

Answer (score 0):

You can save them in array, then output in the end like this, check the [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a694d8e05dc22d1377a57da4e4e44be33deec74)

```
$string = '2019-08-21 13:30:00,2019-08-20 16:30:00,2019-08-29 13:30:00,2019-08-28 13:30:00,2019-08-22 13:30:00,2019-08-30 13:30:00,2019-08-28 15:00:00,2019-08-28 11:33:00,2019-08-21 12:22:00,2019-08-23 12:22:00,2019-08-29 16:00:00,2019-08-25 15:00:00,2019-08-30 16:00:00';
$date_times = explode(",",$string);

$result = [];
foreach($date_times as $date_time){
    $date = date('l,j', strtotime($date_time));
    $time = date('H:i', strtotime($date_time));
    $result[$date][] = $time;
}
foreach($result as $k=>$v){
    echo "$k\t" . join("\t",$v)."\n";
}
```

output

```
Wednesday,21    13:30   12:22
Tuesday,20      16:30
Thursday,29     13:30   16:00
Wednesday,28    13:30   15:00   11:33
Thursday,22     13:30
Friday,30       13:30   16:00
Friday,23       12:22
Sunday,25       15:00
```